# How to sum total row and the bottom of the data

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my lines of code

```
sub test
    Dim VR As Long
    VR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(J2:J" & VR & 
    ")"
Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(L2:L" & VR & 
")"
Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(M2:M" & VR & 
")"
Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(N2:N" & VR & 
")"
Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(O2:O" & VR & 
")"
Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(P2:P" & VR & 
")"
Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(Q2:Q" & VR & 
")"
Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(R2:R" & VR & 
")"
Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(S2:S" & VR & 
")"
Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(T2:T" & VR & 
")"
Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(U2:U" & VR & 
")"
Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=sum(V2:V" & VR & 
")"
end sub
```

I have these lines of code that sum up every column of data but how do I sum these cells?

Comment: Where would you like the sum to be returned?

Comment: column x in the same row as the other totals

Comment: What happened to column K?

Comment: column k is blank as it acts as a divider between the data and the columns i have created

Comment: If the last row is always the same, then you can insert this formula into all your columns in one step btw, instead of all the lines you have right now.

Comment: The last row for every column will be the same, how can i enter it in one step? @BigBen

Comment: See my "answer"...

Comment: @BigBen how would i sum those lines after it?

Comment: That's the answer from @FaneDuru.

Answer (score 1):

Try, please:

```
Range("X" & VR + 2).formula = "=sum(J" & VR + 2 & ":V" & VR + 2 & ")"
```

Comment: @BigBen: You are right! It should be two rows down from his `Rows.count`...

Comment: @BigBen: If all the existing formulas are returned in `Range("..." & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)` and he needs the new formula on the same row, I think it should...

Comment: @BigBen: Of course! I said a stupid thing. I will delete my answer...

Comment: @BigBen: I know that (now), but it does not deserve to remain here...

Comment: @BigBen:  It may be, but it is not mine, anymore... :)

Comment: @BigBen:  Of course, again... In the meantime other row has been added...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but a probably a huge simplification, to insert the formula into all the columns in one step:

```vb
Dim VR As Long
VR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim VR2 As Long
VR2 = VR + 2 ' I'm assuming that you just need to offset the last row by 2

Range("J" & VR2 & ",L" & VR2 & ":V" & VR2).Formula = "=sum(J2:J" & VR & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have range of columns which you want to sum. For each column you want to:

- sum all values that exist in a column,
- write sum 2 cells below last row.

Currently, you get the last row for H column and apply it to every column, which might not be valid. Just imagine that last row for H column is 25th and for J column it is 27th. You would write sum of J2:J25 in cell J27 and overwrite value in J27.

So I recommend writing loop over set of columns and apply listed above actions:

```
cols = Array("J", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V")
rowsCnt = Rows.Count
' This variable will contain sum of all values
totalSum = 0
For i = LBound(cols) to UBound(cols)
    lastRow = Range(cols(i) & rowsCnt).End(xlUp)
    colSum = Application.Sum(Range(cols(i) & "2"), Range(cols(i) & lastRow))
    Range(cols(i) & (lastRow + 2)) = colSum
    ' Here you sum all column sums
    totalSum = totalSum + colSum
Next
```